# Python 3.5 - Number Picker game, while loop & variables(beginner)

Tags: python, loops, variables, while-loop, boolean

so i am quite new to python and there seems to be a problem with my while loop or the boolean win value, it keeps asking for another number even after i have won. There is also a problem with my life variable as whenever i get an answer wrong it comes up with an error; "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'lives' referenced before assignment"
ps. the 'random' number is always 45 so i can easily win to sort out problems
[lives variable pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfIMn.png)
[while loop problem pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMerr.png)
    import random
    import time

```
def compare():
 if guess == rand_num:
    print("You guessed correct!")
    win = True
 elif guess > rand_num:
    print ("Guess lower!")
    lives = lives - 1
 else:
    print ("Guess higher!")
    lives = lives - 1

win = False
rand_num = 45
lives = 10
while lives > 0:
 if win == False:
     guess = int(input("Guess a number!"))
     compare()
time.sleep(3)
print("Well done!")
```

Comment: Functions should have a separation of concern.  Your compare method is actually compareAndPrintAdjustLivesAndSetWinCondition().  Consider writing a compare which returns -1, 0, 1.  Based on that have whoever called it print and adjust the lives.  No more globals, separation of concerns, cleaner code.

Comment: You should always state the error message received in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the beginning of your compare function add the line `global lives`.

The error that you are getting `local variable lives referenced before assignment` means that you are accessing a local variable, but that variable does not exist.  In this case, you need to tell python that the variable is not local, but is a global variable.

This wouldn't happen if you were not assigning a value (for example, just having `print(lives)` in the function compare.  In that case, the python interpreter would use the global value.  The fact that you are assigning to the variable causes python to treat it as a local variable, and in order to do the assignment, you need to compute `lives - 1` before you have assigned any value.  The line `global lives` causes it to use the variable in the module instead of creating a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, your code is taking for granted that the "compare" function will know what variables to use. Functions do not know what values to use inside unless you explicitly define or provide those variables. To fix your code, you should write:

```
def compare(guess, lives, rand_num):
    ...
```

instead of using compare() with no arguments. Then, in your while loop, instead of calling "compare()", you would pass the two variables to the function like so:

```
compare(guess, lives, rand_num)
```

You also need to make sure that the while loop breaks when you win so that it does not run forever. Your while loop should now look like this:

```
while lives>0:
    if win==False:
        guess = int(input("Guess a number!"))
        compare(guess, lives, rand_num)
    if win==True: #you could also write "if win:"
        break
```

This way, your loop will terminate when you win.

Answer (score -1):

First, add global lives in the beginning of your function, then turn the if statement to part of the while loop, like so:

```
def compare():
    global lives,win
    if guess == rand_num:
        print("You guessed correct!")
        win = True
    elif guess > rand_num:
        print ("Guess lower!")
        lives = lives - 1
    else:
        print ("Guess higher!")
        lives = lives - 1
win = False
rand_num = 45
lives = 10
while lives > 0 and win == False:
    guess = int(input("Guess a number!"))
    compare()
time.sleep(3)
print("Well done!")
```